# Sample down Image from Inputstream without decoding to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to find a solution to be able to download an image from Url into the Filesystem and resize it without the need to decode it to a bitmap first.

The only solution I could find yet was the approach to decode it to a bitmap with  specific SampleSize. However, the problem here is that a lot of memory is consumed when creating the bitmap which would limit the maximum size of the image depending on the free memory available on the device. Another Problem is that it takes a lot of time to decode it to a Bitmap and also to compress it back to an output stream.

My current code looks like this (options1 contains the original dimensions, calculateSampleSizeForImageSize() calculates the sampleSize for smaller required Imagesize):

```
 if (maximumImageSize  < Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4f) {
                //enough memory free to reduce size
                //reduce size
                BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options2.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSizeForImageSize(options1, maximumImageSize);
                options2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options2);
                try {
                    //write reduced size bitmap to picture file
                    os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
                    os.flush();
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    return 0;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed to fetch image", e);
                    throw new IOException(e);
                } finally {
                    closeStream(os);
                    closeStream(is);
                }
```

So is there a way to bypass the bitmap and directly write the input stream in reduced size to the output stream?

Comment: I don't think so. Sampling is a bitmap operation, requiring you to apply a transforming Matrix to the array of pixels hold by Bitmap. If you want to do it directly on an InputStream, which is basically a stream of bytes, you would have to do this matrix transformation manually, which would be a lot of work!